# Check whether $e^x(1-e^x)\le \frac{1}{4}$ is true or false.

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, proof-verification

> Check whether the inequality is true/false:
>
> $\hspace{50mm}e^x(1-e^x)\le \frac{1}{4}$   $ \hspace{20mm}\forall x<0$

Consider $f(x)=e^x(1-e^x)- \frac{1}{4}$.

Then $f^{'}(x)=e^x(1-e^x)+e^x(-e^x)=0\implies e^x-2e^{2x}=0\implies e^x(1-2e^x)=0$

Since $e^x\neq 0\implies e^x=\frac{1}{2}$

Now $f^{'}(x)>0$ whenever $e^x<\frac{1}{2}\implies x<-\log 2<0\implies f(x)$ is increasing for $x<0$

So $f(x)\le f(x_0)$ where $e^{x_0}=\frac{1}{2}$

$\implies f(x)\le 0\implies e^x(1-e^x)\le \frac{1}{4}$ Q.E.D.

Please check my proof

Comment: The statement is indeed true, but your argument is incomplete as it stands. The second derivative test implies only that $f$ has a *local* maximum, not a global maximum. To conclude that $f(x)\leq f(x_0)$ for *all* $x$, rather than just $x$ sufficiently close to $x_0$, you need to give an argument that $f(x_0)$ is the global maximum.

Comment: Seems good to me.  For style points I wouldn't put the -1/4 in defining f.  We finding max so constants don't matter.  We you have $e^x = 1/2$ you should state x = $\ln 1/5$ and mention that it does actually exit.

Comment: $$e^x(1-e^x)-\frac{1}{4}=-\left(e^x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2{}{}{}{}{}\leqslant0$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My comment points out that your argument is incomplete as it stands. The second derivative test implies only that you have found a local maximum, not a global maximum. You need to argue that your maximum is global.

Here is a **hint** for a solution without calculus: recall that the AM-GM inequality says $a+b\geq2\sqrt{ab}$ when $a, b\geq0$. So when $e^x, 1-e^x\geq0$, we have$$e^x+1-e^x=1\geq 2\sqrt{e^x(1-e^x)}$$
What about the case when $1-e^x<0$?

Comment: I have edited my answer;Please check

Comment: @S.Bandopadhaya: I would also point out explicitly that $f'<0$ (so $f$ decreasing) for $x>x_0$.

Comment: That's a goodsolution

Answer (score 1):

As **symplectomorphic** said in the comments, you still need to show that your maximum is a global maximum; this is easily done by considering the sign of $f'(x)$.

For another solution without calculus, let $u=e^x$, so that $f(x)=u(1-u)$. The graph of $y=u(1-u)$ is a parabola opening down, so it attains its maximum at its vertex. It has zeroes at $u=0$ and $u=1$, so its vertex is on the line $u=\frac12$, specifically, at $\langle\frac12,\frac14\rangle$. Thus, $f(x)$ attains its maximum of $\frac14$ at $e^x=u=\frac12$, i.e., at $x=\ln\frac12=-\ln 2$.

Comment: yes that was quite good